# spreadsheet with cities and states

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a spreadsheet with data that would be similar to cities and states that I need to lookup and concatenate info into a single cell. I am using excel. I'm using cities and states as an example because it is closest to the set of data.

Example:

```
| State | City |
|:------|:---------|
| MA | Worcester|
| MA | Boston|
| MA | Westford|
| PA | Pittsburgh|
| PA | Washington|
| PA | Philadelphia|
```

I need the data displayed like this using the previous data set

```
| State | Cities|
|:----|:-----|
| MA | Worcester, Boston, Westford |
| PA | Pittsburgh, Washington, Philadelphia |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried pivot table to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have these tables:

[image: table]

Then this works in the `Cities` column of the `TableStateCities` table:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableStateCity[State]=[@State],TableStateCity[City],""))
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I was going down the long road of learning DAX to create my own formula for Power Pivot.